# Custom Metadata records Sandbox refresh

Tags: sandbox, custom-metadata, sandbox-refresh

If I create Custom Metadata records in prod, and then I refresh my sandbox, will the Custom Metadata records I created in prod now be in my refreshed sandbox?

I'm considering migrating to a custom metadata type over a custom object, but I'm trying to figure out if it is worth the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. All metadata is copied.

> ## [Refresh Your Sandbox](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_refresh.htm&type=5)
>
> Refreshing a sandbox updates the sandbox’s metadata from its source org. If the sandbox is a clone or if it uses a sandbox template, the refresh process updates the org’s data in addition to its metadata.

Comment: so a Custom Metadata record == metadata? I feel like boundaries are being crossed :D

Comment: Yes it is metadata. `Custom` **`Metadata`**.

Comment: A little confused why the drive by down vote.

Answer (score -4):

I believe the question seems a little ambiguous and hence adding another answer.

**Metadata** and **Custom Metadata Types** are 2 entirely different things and showcase different behaviours, during Sandbox Refreshes.

**Salesforce Metadata**

> Metadata in Salesforce is structural and to some extent behavioural
>   information maintained by the platform for every artefact type created
>   on the org, such as Custom Object, Custom Field, Apex Class etc. *For
>   e.g. When you define an object, the Label the API Name, Description
>   and other details are the metadata.*
>
> Whenever a Sandbox is refreshed from a Production instance, this
>   metadata gets copied over to the Sandbox and overwrites the existing
>   stated of the Sandbox irrespective of the type of the Sandbox being
>   refreshed. If you are referring to records or data stored within an
>   object, then, those are  copied over only in case of Full Copy and
>   Partial Sandboxes using Sandbox Templates.

**Custom Metadata Type**

> [Custom Metadata Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/04/custom-metadata-types-ga.html) on the other hand is a Custom Setting like
>   entity that permits defining custom types which facilitate moving them
>   across instances during deployment. The key advantage is metadata
>   here, is stored as records thus providing the flexibility to transfer
>   them across environments.
>
> They are moved over when Sandboxes are refreshed irrespective of the
>   type.

Comment: A custom metadata type, in the second sense, is a type of metadata, in the first sense. Records of custom metadata types are metadata.